# Using twilio https://www.twilio.com/ Android App To App Calling is possible?

Tags: android, twilio, voip, twilio-php, twilio-click-to-call

Using twilio [https://www.twilio.com/] Android VoIP App To App Calling is possible ?

like as "Whats app calling",  "Ringo Calling", "Tango Calling"

please advice me if other options for VoIP Calling app to app, i already used Sinch app to app https://www.sinch.com

thanks advance

Answer (score 1):

I hope you don't mind my restating your question.  If I understand correctly I believe you're asking if it is possible to build a VoIP app for Android using the Twilo API.  Is this correct?

If that is the case, here is what I found on the website you referenced:

> Want your Android app to make and receive calls? Look no further!
>   Twilio Client Android is a Java library for Android that enables voice >communications with landlines or other Twilio Client devices, including web >browsers and other mobile devices.

I hope this helps.

Jeremiah

Comment: thanks for replay !! yes, i Want to create app calling using VoIP app to app calling. now i read "twilio SDK" but i am not sure is it possible for me ?

Comment: I believe it is possible.  I would recommend researching the Twilio documentation.  Here (https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/ip-chat/android/java) is a link to a tutorial that should aquatint you with Twilio.  Best of luck.

Comment: Sorry But above doc is a link for chat Messages, i need for calling. i used it but not used for me.

Comment: Here's the documentation for Twilio Client on Android: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/android. If you do get lost on our documentation site, check up towards the top left and there is a search box that you can use to find things you're interested in.